# Efficient way of calculating distance

Tags: php, mysql, distance

I am making a dating site with a search function to find matches. One of the criteria is the distance between you and the possible match. How should I calculate the distance? I think calculating the exact distance for all possible matches might be too resource-intensive.I want a different solution so the nearby people are shown without being resource-intensive.

I had this idea:

When someone registers, save their coordinates rounded to (for the latitude) the nearest 5 minutes (=9 km) in the database? When searching for a match, search trough the database looking for the same coordinates as the user. After the matches are found, the exact distance could still be calculated.

How would that work for the longitude? 
Are there any better ways of doing this?
**I am not looking for the formula for calculating the distance. How can I find nearby matches without having to calculate the distance to every single possible match (thousands)?**

Comment: have a look at the "spatial extensions" in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: The algorithm for doing "by the crow flies" distance calculation is well known and you should be able to find it in literally seconds of googling.

Comment: Why did someone give me a downvote? Is this something I should know, is it a duplicate or did you just feel like giving a downvote?

Comment: @GordonM I edited the post... I meant something else. I don't need the code itself but rather a different way of finding nearby matches.

Comment: For the revised question you can't but you can narrow your SQL results down somewhat by doing abs(thisLat - otherLat) <= whatever threshold you consider acceptable and doing the same for longitude in the query.  This will let you restrict the matches to a square region around the specified lat/long.  Then you can run the more involved calculation on that smaller dataset to get a better number for the distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you can pick the latitude longitude of two users and can convert them into distance as following functions:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}

echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";

?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not bad, but calculating the distance and converting between distance units are two different jobs and as such should be implemented as two different functions.  Keep it modular :)

Comment: I probably wasn't very clear, but this algorithm would have to be run thousands of times every time someone clicks on "Find new matches". That's why I need a different solution probably by saving some data to avoid having to calculate everything so often. I don't need code to calculate a distance, but I need a better way of finding nearby matches. Anyway thanks.